# utf-8 coding problems using python pyodbc to connect to a Sybase Database in a Docker container

Tags: python, docker, utf-8, dockerfile, pyodbc

When I create a connection using `pyodbc`

```
connectionString = ('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT='+port+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password+';DATABASE='+db_environment)
db_connection_dw = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
cursor = db_connection_dw.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_query_string)
print(cursor.fetchone())
```

I get weird results regarding fields of type `CharField` that contains specials characters.
For example I get 'M\x8adic' instead of 'Mèdic'

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8

ADD devartodbcase_amd64.deb /tmp/devartodbcase_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get clean && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales locales-all && \
    locale-gen ca_ES.UTF-8 && \
    apt-get install -y gettext libgettextpo-dev g++ unixodbc unixodbc-dev libaio1 && \
    cd /tmp/ && dpkg -i devartodbcase_amd64.deb

ENV LANG ca_ES.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL ca_ES.UTF-8

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip==20.0.2 && pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app/ /app
```

requirements.txt

```
Django==2.2.7
djangorestframework==3.10.3
django-filter==2.2.0
psycopg2==2.8.4
pyodbc==4.0.28

numpy==1.18.1
pandas==1.0.1

python-decouple==3.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0

django-widget-tweaks==1.4.5

SQLAlchemy==1.3.13
```

Is the problem caused by the driver configuration, the Dockerfile configuration?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `driver` in your Python code?

Comment: If I call `pyodbc.drivers()` I get `['ODBC Drivers', 'Devart ODBC Driver for ASE']` do you refer to that?

Comment: I was referring to the value you are embedding into your connection string: `connectionString = ('DRIVER='+driver+...`

Comment: Ah, sorry. My driver variable is `{Devart ODBC Driver for ASE}`

Comment: Hard to say where `\x8a` might be coming from. "è" is UTF-8 encoded as `C3 A8` so if you were getting `\xa8` it would make more sense. You might want to see if you can get a definitive answer from Devart as to what encoding their driver uses.

Answer (score 0):

You should set connection encoding since DB client get results in some default DB server encoding that could not properly interpreted in your script. You could do it after getting connection with `db_connection_dw.setencoding("utf-8")`. See following manual https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode

Comment: Hi frost-nzcr4, and thanks. I tried exactly this before but it didn't worked

Comment: And this one `db_connection_dw.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding="utf-8")` with `db_connection_dw.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding="utf-8")`?

Comment: Yes, I tried all of the options available on the pyodbc documentation, including this ones...